# Oracle SQL query that displays the files that have been changed

Tags: sql, database, oracle

There is a table in Oracle where general information about changes to different files in the system is stored. The table contains the file ID, the version of the change (each subsequent field change adds +1 to this value in a new row for each file ID), the user ID (who made the change) and the fields to change (in the example only the "type" column).

Please help me to write a sql query that will display the file IDs of the files in which the type (type2 and type3 in the example) has been changed after the user 12345 in the example.

That is, the query on the current example should show identifiers 111111 and 222222

| ID | Version | UserId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 1 | 12345 | type1 |
| 111111 | 2 | 12345 | type1 |
| 111111 | 3 | **54312** | **type2** |
| 222222 | 1 | 12345 | type1 |
| 222222 | 2 | **54312** | **type3** |
| 333333 | 1 | 12345 | type1 |

Comment: If I am understanding correctly simple `where type in ('type1', 'type2') and userid = 54312` should do the job. What is it that you are finding hard to do exactly?  What query you have tried.

Comment: The question is indeed not clear. So, someone else changed type to something else than *type1* directly **after** user 12345 changed to *type1*? And don't you want to know then which user and what type? Showing only identifiers 1111 and 2222 is not much info

Comment: @jan-doggen I have a program that automatically changes the type. If the type is specified incorrectly, a person (can be with any ID) comes and corrects the type. I need to get the IDs of these files to find out why my program is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use analytic function LAG to find previous user (ordered by version, partitioned by ID)

```
select distinct ID 
from 
(
    select ID, Type,
    lag(UserId) over(partition by id order by version) prevUserId, 
    lag(Type) over(partition by id order by version) prevType      
     from your_table
) s
     where prevUserId = 12345
       and prevType<>Type
```

Comment: I'd assume OP wants a generic query, i.e. detecting changes not only for 12345.

Comment: No, the static ID option works for me.  @leftjoin Unfortunately, your query gives all records, even if nothing has been changed after the required user

Comment: @A.Max Fixed: added check that Type has been changed

Comment: @leftjoin in this case the error: "ORA-00904: "Type": invalid identifier" on string and prevType<>Type, but when I added the Type to the nested select after **ID,**, and "asc" in the order by it worked. Thank you!